# How to go back to previous view controller without popping to allow for forward navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a navigation controller and want to allow moving to the previous view controller on the stack and then returning back to the current view controller.

For example, if my navigation controller has 3 view controllers A, B, and C on the stack and I am currently in C, then in C I want to have options to either move back to B or to push a new view controller D. When going back from C to B, I want B to have the option to move forward to return to the same instance of C so that no text fields are cleared on B.

Is there any way to go back to B without popping C from the navigation controller?

Ideally I am looking for a way to make this scalable so that if I have 50 view controllers on the stack I can go all the way back to the first and then keep going forward through all of them until reaching the 50th again where I can keep pushing more view controllers.

Comment: Why though? What is your use case? I can't think of a situation were keeping VC's in memory would be the best solution to any problem.

Comment: I agree. It would be simpler to have the new instance of C configure itself with the current state.  Your state should be independent of any view elements (text field etc)

Comment: @FruitAddict Each view controller is for the user to set up info that will all be sent to the API at the end. I want them to be able to go back and change some data without having to clear any data on the forward view controllers.

Comment: @Mark you should think of a better view controller structure to save and make api calls imo